# Borrar un string determinado UNA VEZ

Tags: java

Estoy trabajando en un editor de texto. Para lo que sirve el siguiente código, es para buscar una determinada palabra y resaltarla, esto funciona sin problema . El fallo esta en que tengo un botón para buscar la siguiente palabra que coincida con la de la búsqueda.
El problema es que quiero borrar una palabra determinada de un String que obtengo de un Textfield, pero de uno en uno.

La siguiente linea borra la palabra deseada, pero todas las veces que aparece en el texto de golpe. **Lo que quiero es que se borre una sola vez, por cada iteración, no todo de golpe.**

```
buffer.replaceAll(palabra, "");
```

Con la función "replace()" obtengo el mismo resultado.

Lo que quiero es borrar la primera vez que aparece la palabra del string buffer. Este string lo he creado para ir borrando las palabras que aparecen en el string original ,texto, que es el que contiene el contenido del scrollArea. No consigo determinar cual sería la lógica para hacerlo. Pongo un ejemplo:

Tengo en el string texto la siguiente cadena: Hola a hola a hola. 
Lo que hace el replaceAll es borrar de esta manera: a a. Ha borrado todas las veces "hola". Lo que quiero es que se borre de uno en uno.

Ahora os muestro todo el código del método en cuestión:

```
String texto, sentencia, palabra = "", buffer;
                texto = textArea.getText();
                buffer = texto;
                sentencia = campo.getText();
                String[] palabraBuscar = sentencia.split("\\W+"); 
                for(int i = 0; i < palabraBuscar.length; i++){
                    palabra = palabra + palabraBuscar[i];
                }
                String[] palabraTotales = texto.split("\\W+"); 
                    while(buffer.contains(palabra)) {
                        try {
                            System.out.println("Encontrado");
                            Highlighter highlighter = textArea.getHighlighter();
                            HighlightPainter painter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.red);
                            int p0 = texto.indexOf(palabra);
                            int p1 = p0 + palabra.length();
                            highlighter.addHighlight(p0, p1, painter);
                            buffer = buffer.replaceAll(palabra, "");
                            repaint();
                        } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(Editor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Con la función replace tengo el mismo resultado.

Comment: El bucle está para que una vez que se hayan borrado todas cadenas de búsqueda no encuntre match con el string buffer. El blucle se para cuando, buffer.contains(palabra) == false

Comment: No estoy teniendo problemas de bluces infinitos. Es más sale de el la primera vez, aun estando repetida la palabra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al estar utilizando el `String.replaceAll`, está reemplazando todo lo que coincida, debería utilizar `String.replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement)`, para que solo reemplace su primera coincidencia.

Comment: Perfecto, justo lo que estaba buscando. Gracias!